# What's the proper way to save messages sent to telegram bot with python (telegram.ext)?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I need my bot to save messages it receives and put them in a database after the certain button is pressed. It works alright as far as I'm the only one using it, but when I tested it with another user, queries started to mix with each other. It must be because I'm using global variables to save the query data (date, sender, context, etc.) before the button is pressed, but can't figure another way to make it work right. Can somebody help?

Here're my functions I use with coversationhandler

```
FIRST,SECOND,THIRD,Q_DONE = range(4)
ONE, TWO = range(2)
date = ""
sender = ""
text = ""
sender_name = ""
type = ""
category = ""
image = ""
m_id = ""

def start (update,context):

    buttons = [['Отправить заявку ИТО', 'Отправить заявку УПСИ', 'Заявка выполнена']]
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                             reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(buttons, resize_keyboard=True), text="Введите текст и нажмите <отправить заявку>:")
    return FIRST

def get_query (update,context):
    global category, date, sender, text, sender_name, type, image, m_id
    sender = update.message.chat.id
    date = update.message.date
    sender_name = update.message.from_user.first_name + update.message.from_user.last_name
    m_id = update.message.message_id
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=constants.DBhost,
        user=constants.DBuser,
        passwd=constants.DBpasswd,
        database=constants.DBdatabase,
    )
    mycursor = db.cursor(buffered= True)
    query = update.callback_query
    type = update.message.text
    if (type == "Отправить заявку ИТО"):
        type = "ИТО"
        mycursor.execute('SELECT name FROM categories WHERE type IN (SELECT id FROM types WHERE name = "%s")' % type)
        categories = mycursor.fetchall()
        buttons = []
        for name in categories:
            si = str(', '.join(name))
            buttons += [[InlineKeyboardButton(text=si, callback_data="category_" + si)]]
        buttons += [[InlineKeyboardButton(text="Отмена", callback_data="cancel")]]
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons, n_cols=2),
                                 text="Выберите категорию заявки:")
        return SECOND
    if (type == "Отправить заявку УПСИ"):
        type = "УПСИ"
        mycursor.execute('SELECT name FROM categories WHERE type IN (SELECT id FROM types WHERE name = "%s")' % type)
        categories = mycursor.fetchall()
        buttons = []
        for name in categories:
            si = str(', '.join(name))
            buttons += [[InlineKeyboardButton(text=si, callback_data="category_" + si)]]
        buttons += [[InlineKeyboardButton(text="Отмена", callback_data="cancel")]]
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons, n_cols=2),
                                 text="Выберите категорию заявки:")
        return SECOND
    if (type == "Заявка выполнена"):
        u_id = update.message.chat_id
        mycursor.execute("SELECT id FROM messages WHERE sender_id=%s AND status=0" % u_id)
        arr = [item[0] for item in mycursor.fetchall()]
        if len(arr) == 0:
            context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Нет незакрытых заявок!")
        if len(arr) == 1:
            print(arr[0])
            mycursor.execute("UPDATE messages SET status = 1 WHERE id=%s;" % arr[0])
            db.commit()
            mycursor.execute("SELECT context FROM messages WHERE id=%s" % arr[0])
            msg = [item[0] for item in mycursor.fetchall()]
            mycursor.execute("SELECT date FROM messages WHERE id=%s" % arr[0])
            date = [item[0] for item in mycursor.fetchall()]
            context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Закрыта заявка '%s'" % msg)
        if len(arr) > 1:
            buttons = []
            for n in arr:
                mycursor.execute("SELECT context FROM messages WHERE id=%s " % n)
                db.commit()
                si = str(', '.join(mycursor.fetchone()))
                buttons += [[InlineKeyboardButton(text=si, callback_data="query_" + str(n))]]
            buttons += [[InlineKeyboardButton(text="Отмена", callback_data="cancel")]]
            context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                                     reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons, n_cols=2),
                                     text="Выберите заявку:")
            return Q_DONE
        return FIRST
    if (text != ""):
        text += "\n"
    text += str(update.message.text)
    db.close()
    mycursor.close()

def category_handler (update,context):
    global category, date, sender, text, sender_name, type, image, m_id
    print("category_handler starts")
    query = update.callback_query
    category = query.data
    category = category[9:]
    query.edit_message_text(text="Отправлена заявка категории: %s"%category)
    update.callback_query.answer()
    print("Pushing into DB!")
    print(date, sender, text, sender_name, type, category)
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
         host=constants.DBhost,
         user=constants.DBuser,
         passwd=constants.DBpasswd,
         database=constants.DBdatabase,
     )
    mycursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO messages (date,sender_ID,context,sender_Name,type,category,image,status) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,0);"
    mycursor.execute(sql, [date, sender, text, sender_name, type, category,image])
    text = ""
    image = ""
    db.commit()
    db.close
    mycursor.close()
    return FIRST
```

Answer (score 1):

`context.user_data['']` can be used to save variables between users and handlers.